# Spring Boot + Angularjs controller showing special char at runtime

Tags: angularjs, spring

I have a simple spring boot angular app. In some controller methods it is showing some special char at runtime.I have checked the encoding it is UTF-8.

**code on controller**

```
 $scope.onSupplierSelect = function(selectedItem){
         $scope.domain['supplier'] = selectedItem;
        if(selectedItem.name){
         $scope.domain['supplier'].name = $scope.domain['supplier'].name;
       }
        }
```

**code showing on browser**

```
$scope.onSupplierSelect =Â function(selectedItem){
        Â Â Â Â $scope.domain['supplier'] = selectedItem;
        Â Â Â Â if(selectedItem.name){
        Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â $scope.domain['supplier'].name = $scope.domain['supplier'].name;
        Â Â Â Â }
        }
```